# Creating a Dynamic Property so i can insert values into a certain position

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, properties-file

So i am having trouble finding/doing a property i set in my property file that values can be inserted into based on a position.

For example i would have this im my property file.

test.transfer=Transfer {0} {1} - {2}

In these position i would insert my corresponding value and then that whole string would be used for my final value.

FINAL VALUE:  Transfer from ME - 123123132

I know i could write some java code but i believe java or spring already have these cover i just cant figure out what its called or how this is done.

Any help or ideas is welcome.

Comment: Springs I18N support already provides this out of the box. What is it you need it for?

Comment: well i know it existed but didnt know how to invoke it. I need it to make a customer String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at MessageFormat (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)?

Comment: these may be what i am looking for i could not find the correct wording.